# Salesforce Dom dynamic behaviour

Tags: dom, selenium, shadow-dom

Last week the structure is with li elements and now the HTML structure is changed.  This is for Salesforce Contacts object.Please see the image.

```
<div id="suggestionsList">
    <ul>....</ul>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
    <li>...</li>
</div>
```

Confirmed with developers, and there is no change in component file. Please suggest what might be the reason??

```
    <search_lightning-instant-results-list>
    <search_lightning-instant-results-list-item/>
    <search_lightning-instant-results-list-item/>...
</search_lightning-instant-results-list-item/>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Were you always using [Einstein Search](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.search_einstein.htm&type=5)? If someone enabled that, that could explain the change.

Regardless of the above, every release notes Salesforce mentions that [DOM API changes may require UI Test updates](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_lwc_ui_testing.htm&type=5&release=232).

> The content and structure of HTML, CSS, and the DOM can change at any
> time and can’t be considered a stable API. Automated UI tests that use
> tools like Selenium WebDriver to reach into component internals
> require your ongoing maintenance.

Not to mention they do not guarrante backward-compatible HTML, CSS, or DOM

> We’re calling out the fragility of these tests due to changes, in
> particular as Lightning Experience continues to evolve with modern web
> standards. We understand the value that you gain from automated UI
> testing and the maintenance burden these changes put on you.
> **Salesforce has never guaranteed backward-compatible HTML, CSS, or DOM**.

Even so, there's a group for [Test Automation Trailblazers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/groups/0F93A000000DQPdSAO#discussion) that can be of use for questions/issues.

Answer (score 0):

The Salesforce UI is being converted completely to [Lightning Web Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc) (LWC). In practice, this means that the internal structure of standard components may change from time to time, and these changes may not be announced or externally documented, since developers aren't supposed to depend on them. When possible, use relative references (e.g. childElements) instead of specific names to search for.

Comment: Helpful Answer..Thank you